# inheritance of type aliases within templates

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, alias

It looks like I an inherit type aliases among classes, but not among class templates?  I don't understand why this code works:

```
#include <iostream>

//template<typename T>
struct Test1
{
//    using t1=T;
    using t1=int;
};

//template<typename T>
struct Test2: public Test1//<T>
{
  t1 x;  
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
//    Test2<int> a;
    Test2 a;
    a.x=5;
    std::cout << a.x << std::endl;
}
```

and this code does not:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct Test1
{
    using t1=T;
};

template<typename T>
struct Test2: public Test1<T>
{
  t1 x;  
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Test2<int> a;
    a.x=5;
    std::cout << a.x << std::endl;
}
```

Do types not inherit through templates?

Comment: `t1` in the second example is a *dependent name* (because the base class, where it stems from, is a template dependent on the template parameter of `Test2`), use `typename Test2::t1`.

Comment: @xeo, yeah, you are right, that works, but I am wondering why...

Comment: @Xeo, that does it.  I thought for sure you'd made a typo, and I'd need `typename Test1<T>::t1`.  I don't, and I'm much happier using `typename Test2::t1`.  Thanks.

Comment: @GB: Yeah, it doesn't matter which one you choose, but since you don't need the template arguments for the so-called *injected class-name* (`Test2` here, which just expands to `Test2<T>`), I tend to prefer that.

Comment: @Xeo The `t1` inside `Test2` in the second example is *not* a dependent name. Dependent names are resolved at template instantiation time, non-dependent names are resolved when the template is parsed. The entire problem here is that the OP expects `t1` to be dependent when it is in fact not.

Comment: @Casey: Yes, yes it is. It is a name inside of `Test1`, a class template, which is instantiated with a template parameter of `Test2`, making it a dependent type (it *depends* on the value of `T` to become a complete type). And members of a dependent type are dependent names.

Comment: @Xeo If it *was* a dependent name, the code would compile correctly. That's why the fix is to change the code to *make* it a dependent name, i.e., a name that depends directly or indirectly on a template parameter.

Comment: @Casey: Ah, I see how we're talking about the same thing, with different words. :) I was talking with the corrected code in mind, while you were on about the broken one. In the end, we mean the same thing, I think.

Comment: @Xeo Yes, I'm sure we both know how two-phase name lookup works. But the OP definitely does not, and I'm trying to be sure we don't confuse him about the terminology.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following will work:

```
 typename Test1<T>::t1 x;
```

and, as Xeo points out in the comments above, so does:

```
typename Test2::t1 x;
```

Comment: Yes, but as @Xeo points out above, so will `typename Test2::t1 x` which has the advantages of requiring less typing, less punctuation, and keeps all references relative to the derived class.

Comment: Sounds good! But feels a little counter-intuitive to call Test2's static element while implementing Test2. However, perfectly valid.

Comment: It makes the inheritance cleaner to me.  If I choose to later change the definition to `struct Test2: public OtherTest<T>`, I don't need to hunt for the dependencies through the implementation.  Actually, I think if I reference the typename to `Test1<T>` and then change the baseclass but miss the textual dependency, I'll wind up silently using the `Test1<T>::t1` even though my inheritance structure implies otherwise.

Comment: Cool, nice way to carry types from a struct. Now I see @GB's rationale.