# Why are public aliases not being inherited in this template class?

Tags: c++, templates

```
#include <string>

template <class StringType>
class mytype
{
    struct mybase
    {
        using Type = StringType;
    };

    class mychild : public mybase
    {
        typename Type somevalue;
    };
};

int main()
{
    mytype<std::string> mt;
}
```

It produces this error:

error C3646: 'somevalue': unknown override specifier

message : see reference to class template instantiation 'mytype::mychild' being compiled

message : see reference to class template instantiation 'mytype' being compiled

error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

Why is this not allowed?

Comment: Why the `typename`?

Comment: Not having typename before the type was an issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17913129/inheritance-of-type-aliases-within-templates) so I through that might be an issue for me as well. Wasent 100% sure if its required or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mybase` is a *dependent base class*, because you could add arbitrary specializations of `mytype<T>::mybase` for some type `T`, so that it has different members.

Therefore the compiler cannot know at the point of definition of `mychild` that `Type` is a member of the base class. You could specialize it later to *not* have a `Type` member for some specializations. But the compiler needs to know whether `Type` is a type or not to parse the declaration. Names are not looked in dependent base classes for this reason.

You need to tell the compiler that you are sure that `Type` is a member of the base class and that it is a type, not something else:

```
class mychild : public mybase
{
    typename mybase::Type somevalue;
};
```

The `typename` here indicates to the compiler that the nested `Type` is really a type, since it can't look this up in the dependent base class at the point of definition for the reasons stated above.

If you then *do* specialize `mytype<T>::mybase` in such a way that it doesn't contain `Type` or `Type` is not a type, then instantiation of the corresponding `mytype<T>::myclass` will fail.

`typename` only makes sense before a *nested* name. If the name is not nested, then either it is not dependent and so can simply be looked up immediately (as the case in your example) or it is a member of the current instantiation, in which case the compiler also can be sure whether it is a type or not with a lookup in the template definition. `typename` before an unqualified name is a syntax error. (Aside from its other meaning in a template parameter.)